# How to stop a running *.JAR file with a batch script?

Tags: java, batch-file, jar

We are facing trouble restarting closing a running *.JAR file `started with the "java -cp"`.

Killing java.exe worked fine.

But... isn't there any smoother way for the application? (It saves data on shut-down)

Also, how can one simulate any key input at the following message `"Enter any key to continue..."`  with a batch file?

Thanks for all help!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The following set of batch scripts can be used to start/stop jars/any program

start-jar.bat

```
start "win_title" java -jar [jar file] [jar options]
```

this basically starts your jar(the program) in a window with title set to "win_title".

you could use another batch to kill the window started

stop-jar.bat

```
TASKKILL /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq win_title
```

Comment: TASKKILL /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq win_title" 
the last quote is missing

Answer (score 0):

Use the PAUSE [message] to wait for a key press:

```
PAUSE Hit any key to continue..
```

As for killing your app, there are JMX ways to do it - but I find an easy way to have a socket listening on a local port and then you can easily send a kill commnad to it and let your program handle the shutdown.

Comment: Oh, I know that with the pause button, but how do I make an application go past that event programatically (within batch)?

Comment: Once it's waiting for a key press it's going to keep waiting - I think you're asking a bit too much of a simple batch file.

Answer (score 0):

The excellent [Java Service Wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org/doc/english/release-notes.html) will let you effortlessly install signal handlers for your Java app.

Answer (score 0):

Have your app create a temp file on startup and periodically check if it still exists. Your batch script can just delete that file to terminate the app.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do some cleaning up before your process is shutdown, take a look at [Shutdown Hooks](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/lang/hook-design.html).

from the Q&A in the link:

> **Okay, but won't I have to write a lot of code just to register a simple shutdown hook?**
>
> No. Simple shutdown hooks can often be written as anonymous inner classes, as in this example:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
    public void run() { database.close(); }
});
```